# Request in Module controller is not executed in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I added one HTTP Request to Simple controller, one HTTP request to Module Controller 1, one HTTP Request to Module Controller 2 as the following image.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Number of threads: 1

Ramp-up:1

Lopp count: 1

After running program, Requests in 2 Module controllers aren't executed, and Request in Simple controller run 2 times with http and https? Why Request in Simple controller run 2 time with http and https? and Why requests in 2 Module controllers aren't executed? Could anyone can help me to explain  in this? Thanks in advance for your help.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why "Why requests in 2 Module controllers aren't executed" as you didn't bother to show your Module Controller configuration, the simplest setup is given in the below image:

[image]

With regards to the "run 2 time with http and https" - it's **your server** which performs the [redirection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections), if you're absolutely sure that you don't want this redirect to happen - you can untick the `Redirect Automatically` and `Follow Redirects` boxes in the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler (or even better in the [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults))

[image]

However I do believe you need to cross check the requests nature/flow with the real browser, if the real browser does the redirection - so must JMeter do, same applies to embedded resources, [headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers), [cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching), etc.

Comment: I updated configure of 2 Module Controllers